# zookeeper with kafka docker images

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile, apache-zookeeper

hi i create new zookeeper container and kafka container

i used this command for run zookeeper

```
docker run -d \
--name zookeeper \
-p 2181:2181 \
jplock/zookeeper
```

and i used this command for run kafka

```
docker run -d \
--name kafka \
-p 7203:7203 \
-p 9092:9092 \
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1 \
-e ZOOKEEPER_IP=127.0.0.1 \
ches/kafka
```

and used this command for create new topic

```
docker run \
--rm ches/kafka kafka-topics.sh \
--create \
--topic senz \
--replication-factor 1 \
--partitions 1 \
--zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181
```

but when create kafka new kafka topic i have this error and stop kafka container

```
[2021-03-03 17:08:35,797] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
    [2021-03-03 17:08:36,898] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
    [2021-03-03 17:08:38,006] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
    Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server '127.0.0.1:2181' with timeout of 30000 ms
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1233)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:88)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:56)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure the images see each other? Maybe reference them as host being the image name or just create a network?

Comment: my container is run with port but when add topic kafka port well close

Answer (score 0):

the solution in network we must network pointer to zookeeper and kafka the

solution is:

**

**1. create new network by docker**

**

```
docker network create kafka-net
```

**2. and now involved your network into zookeeper and kafka like that:**

```
 docker run -d\
--name zookeeper \
--network kafka-net
-p 2181:2181 \
jplock/zookeeper
```

and kafka like this:

```
docker run -d \
--name kafka \
--network kafka-net
-p 7203:7203 \
-p 9092:9092 \
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1 \
-e ZOOKEEPER_IP=zookeeper \
ches/kafka
```